# How to get the stereo_image_proc package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the stereo_image_proc package to deal with the stereo image and get the pointclouds, but get the warning"stereo_image_proc is not running",what should i do, and i can't find the stereo_image_proc in my local computer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235973/how-to-get-the-stereo_image_proc-package?/) by [Sally](https://answers.ros.org/users/27061/sally/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

Assuming that you are using ROS indigo under Ubuntu, you can install stereo_image_proc package by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-stereo-image-proc
```

You can check out [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc)'s wiki page to find out how to play with it.

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0